# Edit data with new Device File Explorer in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android-studio-3.0, android-device-monitor

With a new `Device File Explorer` in `Android Studio 3.1` I can open file from the device and see it's contents in `Android Studio`

[image]

File opens in `edit` mode and when I add some lines, save it and restart `Android Studio` and open this file again it's still empty.

Is there a way to save my changes to the device without clicking upload, locate and manually enter this file path?

Comment: I didn't find a way!

Answer (score 9):

You have to save the file on your computer, edit it and upload back the file on the device.

Comment: How can we put it back ?

Comment: @Marco right click on the folder > Upload...

Comment: Drag & drop from explorer works too